# Can't find form uploaded files

Tags: php, file-upload, windows-7, cygwin

**Problem solved, see bottom**

As per the title I can't find any files uploaded through a form.  A little background, here are my files and output:

**test.php**

```
<form action="readfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <input type="file" name="userfile" />
    <input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

**readfile.php**

```
<?php

echo "upload_tmp_dir=".ini_get("upload_tmp_dir")."\n";

var_dump($_FILES);

?>
```

**readfile.php output**

```
ini_set= upload_tmp_dir= 
array(1) {   ["userfile"]=>   array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "flashcardinput.txt"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "text/plain"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpau1N3q"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(106)   } }
```

I'm using cygwin on windows 7, and can't find phpau1N3q in /tmp or C:\Windows\Temp .  As you can see the PHP setting `upload_tmp_dir` is undefined, but using `ini_set("upload_tmp_dir","/somedir")` seemingly has no effect.

Has anyone faced this problem before? 
Thanks!

**EDIT**
I didn't know the file would be deleted automatically upon script conclusion.
Adding

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], "/uploads/upload.txt")){
    echo "MOVE FAILED\n";
}
```

saved it in /uploads/upload.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should move your uploaded file to a new directory or database.

[use `move-uploaded-file` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: That would be the next step, yes, but I have to find it first :)

Comment: i think $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"] could get it, you can't find it in "/tmp" because it will be removed after php progress.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know the file is deleted after the script concludes. Problem solved, thanks!